# HTML grid not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to have these divs displayed as a grid, but I am running into some issues when using the grid method. For some reason, certain images are being cut off and are being displayed unusually on the screen. Some of the divs also don't have the button or text below them as they should.

[image: Image 1]

```css
.container-2 {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container-2">
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/shirt-men-181dmv4-600.jpg" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's slim fit blue plaid shirt</h2>
        <p>$50.00</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <p class="border-bottom"></p>
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://watchdreamer.com/sites/default/files/styles/soldat_md/public/2021-05/WBP201A.BA0632_.png?h=7afb1587&itok=EH_sMV2B" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's silver and black time piece</h2>
        <p>$499.99</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>  
      <p class="border-bottom" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="800"></p>
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/5/Brown-Men-Shoes-PNG-Image.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's Uncle Tom dress shoes</h2>
        <p>$44.99</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <p class="border-bottom" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="800"></p>
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/b19cdda5-932f-4862-a7b3-b7440bfb759e_1.87f4ae5495ec75a86d5f6e4572e807d3.jpeg?odnHeight=612&odnWidth=612&odnBg=FFFFFF" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's slim black slim fit dress pants</h2>
        <p>$70.00</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <p class="border-bottom" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="800"></p>
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://www.suitsexpert.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/silk-tie.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's formal red tie</h2>
        <p>$19.99</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You need to apply sizing to your images. They're wild and free. Also, your paragraphs should probably be inside your grid boxes. I'm not sure what they do anyway since there's nothing in them.

Comment: The paragraphs were to add a border-bottom attribute under each specific div, because the other methods of using border-bottom would increase as the screen width would increase which is what I did not want. And, even after setting a specific width using the method the other individual recommended, the issue still persists. The first row of the grid is completely fine, and ever row after is displaying in a way it should not. There is only one other row that shows and even in that row only two images are shown, both of which are cut off.

Comment: That's a misuse of the paragraph element and probably not necessary. I think the problem folks have with your question is that we don't know what your desired outcome is. Maybe you can revise to add an image.

Comment: I apologize, it would not allow me to add the photo before but it has now. It is titled "Image 1" and shows you the grid and how it is being displayed. I have about 8 "boxes" divs in my grid which means all 8 images should be displayed with their descriptions and buttons underneath, yet only 5 are.

Answer (score 0):

As a start this snippet keeps the grid but it forces the imgs to be contained within its grid area using object-fit.

It also takes out the p elements - if you want some sort of line between items then maybe think of using a pseudo before element if a border-bottom wont suffice - it depends on exactly what you want the final look to be.

```css
.container-2 {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 300px;
}
.container-2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;  
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container-2">
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/shirt-men-181dmv4-600.jpg" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's slim fit blue plaid shirt</h2>
        <p>$50.00</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://watchdreamer.com/sites/default/files/styles/soldat_md/public/2021-05/WBP201A.BA0632_.png?h=7afb1587&itok=EH_sMV2B" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's silver and black time piece</h2>
        <p>$499.99</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div> 
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/5/Brown-Men-Shoes-PNG-Image.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's Uncle Tom dress shoes</h2>
        <p>$44.99</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/b19cdda5-932f-4862-a7b3-b7440bfb759e_1.87f4ae5495ec75a86d5f6e4572e807d3.jpeg?odnHeight=612&odnWidth=612&odnBg=FFFFFF" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's slim black slim fit dress pants</h2>
        <p>$70.00</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://www.suitsexpert.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/silk-tie.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's formal red tie</h2>
        <p>$19.99</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```